# Testing AngularJS Service (Factory) with Karma and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

My service (factory) like this:

```
angular.module('App')
  .factory('SalesService', function($http) {
    return {
      getSales: function(data) {
        return $http.get('/sales');
      }
  }
})
```

I got **Unexpected request: GET /sales** when I do:

```
describe('Sales Services', function() {

  beforeEach(module('App'));

  it('should get the sales data', inject(function(SalesServices, $httpBackend) {
    SalesServices.getSales().then(function(data) {
        expect(data.success).toBeTruthy();
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
  }));

});
```

Everything seems OK to me. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Typo here: .getSaless()

Comment: @ppasler fixed the typo, I'm sure that's not the problem

Comment: Another one: `SalesServices` and the factory creates `SalesService` without an 's'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to `inject` your dependencies in all test, you should use `beforeEach`:

```
var $httpBackend, SalesService;

beforeEach(module('App'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _SalesService_) {
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  SalesService = _SalesService_;
}));
```

Then, in your test you should **expect** the call to some URL:

```
it('should get the sales data', function () {
  // given
  var response = { data: 'result' };
  var result = {}
  $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/sales').respond(200, response);

  // when
  SalesService.getSales().then(function (responseData) {
    result = responseData;
  });
  $httpBackend.flush();

  // then
  expect(result).toEqual(response);
});
```

And at the end you need to make sure that there are no pending requests:

```
afterEach(function () {
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

Comment: what is respond method is doing at `  suite.$httpBackend.expect('GET', '/sales').respond(200, response);
`? my get doesn't take any request param, why i need to pass in the response object here?

Comment: and the `suite` in line 5 come from?

Comment: @ThianKianPhin you can ignore the suite object for now, I removed it. That's additional optimization that we can discuss later.

Comment: $httpBackend is part of ngMocks and that's how it works https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: I make it like this   `$httpBackend.expect('GET', '/sales').respond(200);` and removed `  var response = { data: 'result' };` I still worked. What is response object for?

Comment: @ThianKianPhin great. If it worked then please upvote and accept my answer and I will start a chat below to continue the conversation.